# Add a new field to a MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, pascal

I'm stuck with adding a new field/s to an existing document.

What follows is my procedure AddNewField for testing purposes.

After the code you can see that my collection has two document: the first is Before Update and the second is After Update.

The first (before Update) is the original document containing all the fields.
The last (after Update) has only the "_id" field and the "new_field"

Last but not least I have noticed that while the first document has "_id" : ObjectId("509a2d81f10a00000000000a")
the last document has   "_id" : "509a2d81f10a00000000000a"

I'm trying to use the special update operator $set.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
procedure AddNewField(const aGfs: TGridFS; const  aGfsName: string);
var
  command: IBson;
  bb: IBsonBuffer;
  query: IBson;
  gf: IGridfile;
  OID: string;
begin
  gf := aGfs.find(aGfsName, False);

  OID := gf.getID().AsString;
  query := BSON(['_id', OID]);

  bb := NewBsonBuffer;
  bb.startObject(PAnsiChar('$set'));
  bb.AppendStr(PAnsiChar('new_field'), PAnsiChar('The Boss wins!'));
  bb.finishObject;
  command := bb.finish;

  FMongo.update('fsdb.fs.files', query, command, updateUpsert);
end;
```

---

After the call to FMongo.Update my collection has now two documents!

```
/* Before Update */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("509a2d81f10a00000000000a"),
  "filename" : "Test Document.pdf",
  "length" : NumberLong(7855753),
  "chunkSize" : 262144,
  "uploadDate" : ISODate("2012-11-07T09:44:33Z"),
  "md5" : "e803de3a59bf7098bb419e005162e950",
  "flags" : 0
}

/* After Update */
{
  "_id" : "509a2d81f10a00000000000a",
  "new_field" : "The Boss wins!"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that OID is a string. When you do the update with upsert = true, no document exists with _id =  "509a2d81f10a00000000000a" (string) and so a new document is created with the _id that you have supplied. You need to convert OID into an ObjectID before you use it in this way.